# find the pattern of a given input

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find a pattern from given input output data in hackerrank.com

```
input data :
1
2
3
4
5
10
11
15
20

output data :
1
2
3
4
5
11
22
66
111
```

the problem doesn't have any description and i have to find algorithm for processing the input to become the output.

```
i thought the algorithm was to reverse the number position then add the numbers, examples :
10 +01 =11
15 +51 =66
11 + 11 =22

but it doesn't work for 20, 
20+02 =22?
```

any idea?

Comment: Use back-tracking to find the solution.

Comment: With LaGranger interpolation, you can find infinitely many formulae to match an arbitrary pattern, so such a question amounts to nothing more than "guess what I am thinking."  Mind reading is not scientific.

Answer (score 0):

I found a logic that can satisfy input->output relation. I personally hate these questions, because even though your logic is working, it may differ from question designer. But anyway, this is my method:

```
1-calculate (number of digits-1) for each number
2-add least significant digit of number to it
3-repeat result as much as (other digits of numbers+1)
```

Then it goes as this:

```
1 -> add 1 to 0 (number of digits-1), repeat it 1 time (other digits = 0) -> result is 1
15 -> add 5 to 1 (number of digits-1), repeat it 2 times (other digits = 1) -> result is 66
20 -> add 0 to 1 (number of digits-1), repeat it 3 times (other digits = 2) -> result is 111
```

this method works on all input/output pairs. But I don't know if this is the intended method or not.

Answer (score 0):

For a given number `n` output the `n`-ths palindromic number. The first twenty are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111]` thus e.g. `n = 20 -> 111`